# getting error: Uncaught (in promise) server response is not valid?

Tags: javascript, axios

I am using this on redux thunk with saga, dont know what causes this.[image]

this is the fetchCurrentUser:

```
fetchCurrentUser: () => {
      try {
        const user = axios.get("/api/user/current_user").then(res => res.data.user)
        return user
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('e -', e)
        return null
      }
    },
```

the network request for /api/user/current_user returns successfully but why am i getting this, help?

Comment: are you getting the response as String?

Comment: redux-thunk and redux-saga are kind of mutually exclusive and not represented in the question at all. Please, remove them from tags, if the question is just about axios and promises.

Comment: looks like syntax mistake `try {
  const user = axios.get("/api/user/current_user").then(res => {
    return res.data.user
  });
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from this: you should return `res.data.user` instead of `user`.